# OpenSSL one line base64 input. error reading input file

Tags: encryption, openssl, base64, line-breaks, multiline

I have AES-encrypted file, which encoded to base64 one-line string (without breaklines) and need to decrypt it. [Here it is.](http://pastebin.com/pDN2zkdq)

But when i use:

```
openssl enc -d -a -aes-256-cbc -in encrypted -out decrypted
```

OpenSSL throws "error reading input file"
But base64 util decrypts it like a charm:

```
base64 -d encrypted | openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc > decrypted
```

Trying to find find the cause and convert to one-line base64 file:

```
base64 -w 0 aesfile | openssl enc -d -a -aes-256-cbc > decrypted
# error reading input file

base64 aesfile | openssl enc -d -a -aes-256-cbc > decrypted
# no errors, file decrypted
```

Conclusion: OpenSSL can't decode non-multiline base64 inputs

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your conclusion is correct. Openssl base64 decoding does not work with lines longer than 64 characters. If they are longer, you need to insert a linefeed after every 64 characters.

Answer (score 17):

**Encrypt**

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pass pass:YOURPASSWORD -p -in msg.txt -out enc.txt -base64
```

**Decrypt**

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -base64 -pass pass:YOURPASSWORD -d -p -in enc.txt -out dec.txt
```

If there's no `newline` in the encrypted file after the `base64` line, you get an error saying *`error reading input file`*.

Comment: ie: Trailing newline is required for the base64 string being decrypted.  Thank you for this solution!

Answer (score 0):

If the encryption format is different than the decryption format used in the script, it throws similar error.

Make sure you use the same decryption format used for the file during encryption.